# Can a PCI-E 6 pin cable be used in-place of an 8 pin cable?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, pci-express

I yesterday returned my GTX 960 as it was faulty, and have bought an R9 290, which requires two 8 pin PCI-E cables. I have two 6 pin PCI-E cables, which supplied power the 960.

The only difference between the 6-pin and 8-pin connector is that the 8-pin has two extra grounding pins, and that the 6 pin cable supplies a maximum of 75W and the 8 pin cable supplies a maximum of 150W.

The two cables I have are 18 gauge wires (18AWG), and are sleeved. Another limitation is that the [official specification](https://www.pcisig.com/specifications/pciexpress/) says that PCI-E 6-pin cables can only supply 75W, but the 8-pin cables can supply 150W.

From reading various forums, it seems that it's possible to use a 6 pin PCI-E cable on an 8 pin connector, but however that it depends entirely on the quality of the wire used.

I don't want to use a converter cable as I want have my sleeved cables on display in the case's side-window.

Can the 18AWG 6 pin cable I have be used to power the R9 290, requiring an 8 pin connector?

Comment: I would instead use a [converter cable](http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-Express-Power-Adapter-PCIEX68ADAP/dp/B001TK3TJY), if the extra pins are just grounds, it should exist.  If your asking if the card will work if you use just the 6-pins, my gut says, no it will not.  If your card requires more then 75W this suggestion won't work.

Comment: @Ramhound See my edit. Apparently, [it can work](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/power-supply-specifications-atx-reference,review-32338-12.html), but it depends on the design of the graphics card more than anything else.

Comment: Be sure you answer your question. You should include the relevant information from that article.